# Set button centerHorizontal

Tags: android, button

I know there are some questions about this topic but neither did work for me. I have created a simple button in a RelativeLayout and when I click on it I'd like the button to jump in the middle of the screen. So I have to set the button to CenterHorizontal and CenterVertical programatically. 
Here is my code to set the button centerHorizontal:

```
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)btn.getLayoutParams();

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

When I press the button nothing happens. If anyone has an idea how to fix it please response.

Comment: also show you complete layout code

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a few problems in your code:
1. You have to add the rule after a button click because you create a reference betwen the variable "layoutParams" and the object.
2.You need to get rid of the existing rules.

Sample code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove your align left rules which you have defined in the xml.

```
   Button  btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();
   lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 1);
   lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
   lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
   btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

keep in mind that RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.removeRule is only supported for API >= 17

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's good, but I'd like the app to work on lower API levels too.